# Orgmode Radio tables, pandoc,and docx

Tags: org-mode, pandoc, transclusion

Pandoc's (version 1.13.1) docx converter apparently requires that there be a blank line before the table start and after the table end. With radio tables, this requires a blank line after the `BEGIN RECEIVE` cookie and a blank line before `END RECEIVE`. In order for the orgtbl `SEND` command to create these spaces, I need to specify `:tstart` and `:tend` as follows:

```
<!--
#+ORGTBL: send testtbl orgtbl-to-orgtbl :tstart newline :tend "\\"
| col1 | col2 |
|------+------|
| a    | b    |
| here | is   |
-->

<!-- BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL testtbl -->

| col1 | col2 |
|------+------|
| a    | b    |
| here | is   |

<!-- END RECEIVE ORGTBL testtbl -->
```

My question: Why is different syntax required for `:tstart` and `:tend`? Using newline or "\\" for both doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a question about org-mode or a question about pandoc?

Comment: Good question. I guess that it's really about org-mode, but this issue only arose for me when using pandoc to create a docx file.